# Check for new version of iOS app from App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

I'm checking for new version of app if present on App Store from third party libraries like **Harpy**, **ATAppUpdater**. Except for one app they are giving me the desired result for others.

For one app I'm always getting the result like:

```
{
    resultCount = 0;
    results =     (
    );
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Objective-C **or** Swift?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Objective-C

Comment: Got the solution. My one of the app was country specific. So the iTunes server was not giving me the data for the app. Changing the url to country specific worked.